# How to change all occurrences of a tag to a specific text using `lxml`?

Tags: python, lxml

My home-made solution could be:

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
def tag2text(node, sar):
    """Replace element in `sar.keys()` to text in `sar.values()`."""
    for elem, text in sar.items():
        for ph in node.xpath(f'.//{elem}'):
            ph.tail = text + ph.tail if ph.tail is not None else text
        ET.strip_elements(node, elem, with_tail=False)
```

The above solution at work:

```py
xml = ET.fromstring("""<root><a><c>111</c>
    <b>sdfsf<c>111</c>ddd</b>fff</a>
    <c>111</c><c/><emb><c><c>EMB</c></c></emb></root>""")
tag2text(xml, {'c': '[C]'})
```

which transforms this input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <a><c>111</c><b>sdfsf<c>111</c>ddd</b>fff</a>
  <c>111</c>
  <c/>
  <emb>
    <c>
      <c>EMB</c>
    </c>
  </emb>
</root>
```

into this output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <a>[C]<b>sdfsf[C]ddd</b>fff</a>
  [C]
  [C]
  <emb>[C]</emb>
</root>
```

Looks good.

Any better, more trivial, more efficient, more lxml-ic or more pythonic solution?

Comment: Might be more efficient to do this transformation on the fly while parsing, rather than as a post-processing step directed by xpath, using `iterparse`. Alternatively, since your seeking is trivial `iter()` would probably require less work from lxml than a general-purpose xpath (also you can give it multiple node names somewhat more easily than you can construct a similar xpath filter).

Comment: Not sure why you do the replacement in two passes either, instead of updating the match's tail you could just as easily add the content to the match's previous sibling / parent, and delete the matched element.

Comment: @Masklinn Could you please come up with a better concrete solution in an answer? :)

Comment: This question should better be asked on [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Using `iter` and single-pass replacement:

```py
for node in xml.iter(sar):
    r = sar[node.tag] + (node.tail or '')
    if (p := node.getprevious()) is not None:
        p.tail = (p.tail or '') + r
    else:
        p = node.getparent()
        p.text = (p.text or '') + r
    node.getparent().remove(node)
```

Using `iterparse` and updating the tree as it gets constructed:

```py
ctx = iterparse(BytesIO(doc), tag= sar)
for _, node in ctx:
    r = sar[node.tag] + (node.tail or '') 
    if (p := node.getprevious()) is not None:
        p.tail = (p.tail or '') + r
    else:
        p = node.getparent()
        p.text = (p.text or '') + r
    node.getparent().remove(node)
```

Pretty much the only difference is the iteration part. Both are a touch more complex than the original because they basically have to do the job of `strip_elements` manually.

Both yield the same result:

```xml
<root>
  <a>[C]<b>sdfsf[C]ddd</b>fff</a>
  [C]
  [C]
  <emb>
    [C]
  </emb>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

XML transformations can be handled by XSLT, with saxonche there is a Python package for the latest version XSLT 3 that allows XPath based evaluation so a Python/XSLT 3 version would be:

```
from saxonche import *

xslt = '''
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="replacement-map" static="yes" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" select="map { 'c' : '[C]' }"/>

  <xsl:param name="elements-to-replace" as="element()*">
    <xsl:evaluate context-item="." xpath="(($replacement-map => map:keys()) ! ('//' || .)) => string-join(' | ')"/>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:template match="$elements-to-replace">
    <xsl:sequence select="$replacement-map(local-name())"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
'''
with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as saxon:

    xslt30_processor = saxon.new_xslt30_processor()

    xslt30_executable = xslt30_processor.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_text=xslt)

    xslt30_executable.set_cwd('.')

    xslt30_executable.transform_to_file(source_file='sample1.xml', output_file='result1.xml')
```

I realize another package than lxml doesn't fit the subject's requirement to use lxml but I think it is worth considering XSLT for most XML transformations.

Comment: Could you please tell a bit about the small details of your answer? E.g. about the `elements-to-replace` part?

Comment: @BálintSass, sure, but the relevant parameter in my view is `<xsl:param name="replacement-map" static="yes" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" select="map { 'c' : '[C]' }"/>`, that is an XDM 3.1/XPath 3.1 map that maps element names to replacement strings, similar to your Python dictionary `sar`. The other parameter's value, i.e. the one for the `elements-to-replace`, is then computed by XPath evaluation using `xsl:evaluate`, to select the relevant element nodes. The rest then is XSLT 3 matching those nodes and replacing them with the value found in the map.